# Database is not updated in Celery task with Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery

I'm writing web application with Flask and SQLAlchemy. My program needs to process some stuff in the background and then mark this stuff as processed in the database. Using [standard Flask/Celery example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/), I have something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


app = Flask(__name__)

celery = make_celery(app)

class Stuff(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    processed = db.Column(db.Boolean)


@celery.task()
def process_stuff(stuff):
    # process stuff here

    stuff.processed = True
    db.session.commit()

@app.route("/process_stuff/<id>")
def do_process_stuff(id):
    stuff = Stuff.query.get_or_404(id)
    process_stuff.delay(stuff)
    return redirect(url_for("now_wait"))
```

I can access my database from `process_stuff` (e.g. submit queries like `Stuff.query.get(some_id)` work), but `db.session.commit()` do nothing: my `stuff` record is not updated. According to Celery worker log, commit occures but nothing changes in the database. Is there something wrong with my `db.session.commit()`? Is it possible to make such commit somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I got it. `stuff` passed to `process_stuff()` is not attached to `db.session`. I have to make explicit request in `process_stuff()` to get the right `stuff` object like this:

```py
@celery.task()
def process_stuff(stuff):
    # process stuff here

    my_stuff = Stuff.query.get(stuff.id)

    my_stuff.processed = True
    db.session.commit()
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. I thought that I had properly bound the object I was passing in to db.session but it turned out that I needed to unbind it from the previous session before passing it in. So prior to passing it in I had to put the line db.session.expunge(stuff).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34919555)