# Celery with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy cannot update a database record

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a background celery task with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy to update a property of a database record. I am using the [recommended documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/) for the celery config and this is a simplified version of my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


app = Flask(__name__)

celery = make_celery(app)

class Stuff(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    processed = db.Column(db.Boolean)


@celery.task()
def process_stuff(stuff_id):
    stuff = Stuff.query.get(stuff_id)
    print("stuff.processed 1: {}".format(stuff.processed))
    stuff.processed = True
    print("stuff.processed 2: {}".format(stuff.processed))
    db.session.add(stuff)
    db.session.commit()
    print("stuff.processed 3: {}".format(stuff.processed))

@app.route("/process_stuff/<id>")
def do_process_stuff(id):
    stuff = Stuff.query.get_or_404(id)
    process_stuff.delay(stuff.id)
    return redirect(url_for("now_wait"))
```

And this is the output from the print statements:

```
[2017-07-11 07:32:01,281: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] stuff.processed 1: False
[2017-07-11 07:32:01,282: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] stuff.processed 2: False
[2017-07-11 07:32:01,285: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] stuff.processed 3: False
```

I can see in my celery worker logs that the task is being picked up and completed; however, the print statements show that the `stuff.processed` property is ALWAYS False - the print statement never shows True even after I update it manually (I've tested this outside of celery and I can update the property just fine).

There is a very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883714/database-is-not-updated-in-celery-task-with-flask-and-sqlalchemy) but that solution did not work for my situation

**Library Versions**

- Flask 0.12.2
- SQLAlchemy 1.1.11
- Celery 4.0.2
- Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.2

**Update**

Additional testing shows I can create and persist newly created objects to the database - updating pre-existing objects continues to fail.

Comment: try to add method `def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        db.session.commit()` to `ContextTask`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar no luck unfortunately

Comment: could you add flask, celery, sqlalchemy versions to the question? by the way I can't to repeat your behavior.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar No problem, I've included the libraries. I'm also using postgresql as the database

Comment: If you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy you need to create a request context for the database calls in your celery task. Though I'm not sure why you aren't getting an error that would state that (unless something else is hiding the exception)

Comment: With current identical logging statements, I'm not even sure whether it is 3 consecutive lines printed by the same task, or the same task silently failing the processing after the first line and picking the item immediately again.

Comment: @9000 The logs show a successful execution of the task, but I will update the print statements to delineate. @Cfreak I am using Flask-Sqlalchemy - is the request context you mention separate than the `with app.app_context()` in the above `__call__` function?

Comment: @Anconia I still can't repeat (

Comment: @DanilaGanchar you are able to update and persist the object in the celery task no problem?

Comment: @9000 I retested with updated logging statements and they are indeed 3 consecutive lines printed by the same task

Comment: @Anconia yep. [here app.py](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIORE), [here tasks.py](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIORD). When you change `stuff.processed`(from/to True/False) don't forget to restart celery.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Thank you, I imported all your code directly into my project and Stuff objects can be updated successfully. But when I go to process my actual models it still fails. I'm continuing to investigate - this is quite bizarre.

Comment: @Anconia try to check all imports(compare names of values and modules) and initialization of objects. I'm sure - this is a small defect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my question, I simplified the code substantially and when doing so I changed the `reserved` property to `processed`. My actual model looks more like this:

```
class Stuff(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reserved = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

It turns out that [reserved](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#dump-of-reserved-tasks) is a function in celery, which is why the property could not be updated from my celery task. The solution was to rename the `reserved` property on the model.